# Geojson encoding for using in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've spotted that a geojson encoding utility is now available, [geobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf).

I've played around with the ([python module version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geobuf)) and have been able to encode a geojson file to pbf and then decode back to geojson. I can't figure out how to do this within leaflet.js. I'm hoping this might be a way to encode and deliver large geojson files but I can't find any example as to how to use and implement it in leaflet.js.

Can anyone shed light on how to use geobuf to encode a geojson file and use it with leaflet.js?

Comment: please accept one of the answers if you believe it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [convert Geobuf to plain GeoJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf#decode) in the browser. [Make a geobuf browser build](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf#install), include it in a `<script>` tag (as you do with Leaflet), and then:

```
var layer = L.geoJson( geobuf.decode( new Pbf(data) ) ).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Ivan. Thanks again for helping me out. Twice in one day. You're a star. One more (possibly stupid) question. How should I bring the pbf data into my html file? Should I bring it in like I have done previously with geojson files, where I have defined a variable which I then reference when I initiate my geojson variable (having saved the geojson data as a js file). I.E., the layer like this:  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/COUNT_20160209_NEW.js"></script>and the geojson variable like this: var geojson = L.geoJson(test, {style: style,onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);

Comment: *'test' being my variable that I've defined in the COUNT_20160209_NEW.js file.

Comment: [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the .pbf file from the network.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit green here Ivan, but I don't get what you mean. Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

From leaflet [docs](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) :

`L.geoJson(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);`

Where `geojsonFeature` is the actual geoJSON

Comment: Hi Damien. I think you might have picked my question up incorrectly. I'm looking to find out how to encode a large geojson file (a file that's too large to just bring in to leaflet as is. I'm specifically looking to see if anyone has any knowledge of using the geobuf encoder with leaflet.

Comment: Ah sorry, i see want you mean now, you want the pbf file to be used ? IvanSanchez answers looks correct then.